# Errors running python unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x

My folder structure is:

```
.
- test/modules
|   - parseTests.py
```

The source of `parseTests.py` is copied and pasted from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) (Unittest Basic Example).

When I run `python -m unittest`, no tests are found.
When I run `python -m unittest ./modules/tests/parseTests.py`, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 159, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ValueError: Empty module name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use pytest, you'll have a better time. https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/

Comment: yup, ended up using pytest. :)